# Why is Face ID on used iPhone X and XS often not working?

Tags: iphone, face-id

I have seen plenty of used iPhone X and XS that say the phone works fine except Face ID. This made me quite curious as to why most iPhone X or XS have their face corrupted? Apparently it's a depth camera — are depth cameras more susceptible to faults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest explanation is that they've had their screens broken and the replacements weren't done by Apple themselves.

The FaceID [and TouchID] secure enclave chips cannot be replaced by anyone other than Apple. If they are in any way disturbed by a third party, they will cease to function.
This is a security measure.

Comment: this makes so much sense, its just like home button in iphones that if replace will not function right?

Comment: Correct - different chip but same security measure. I'd avoid buying phones that have been broken by their previous owners. This would be a good indication of how "used" they are… used & dropped ;)

Comment: thanks a lot for the advice. I was indeed planning on purchasing one without face ID but now i changed my mind :)